# Getting index value when using custom Knockout mapping

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm setting up a Knockout ViewModel like this:

```
var Schedule = function(data, parent) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
    self.foo = 'bar';
    ...
};

var ScheduleViewModelMapping = {
    'schedules': {
        create: function(options) {
            return new Schedule(options.data, options.parent);
        }
    }
};

ko.mapping.fromJS(data, ScheduleViewModelMapping, self);

$(document).ready(function() {
    var ViewModel = new ScheduleViewModel;
    ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
});
```

Schedules is an array, and i would like to be able to fetch the index of the current schedule somewhere so i'll be able pass it to the Schedule object along with options.data and options.parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest changing your mapping handler so it can store some state:

```
var ScheduleViewModelMapping = new (function(){
    var counter = 0;

    this.schedules = {
        create: function(options) {
            //use counter as index as required
            var s = new Schedule(options.data, options.parent);
            counter++;
            return s;
        }
    }

    this.resetCounter = function() {
        counter = 0;
    }
})();


ScheduleViewModelMapping.resetCounter();
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, ScheduleViewModelMapping, self);
```